# Not getting "Git remote heroku added" and getting error: "fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly" when pushing to heroku master

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am brand new to Heroku and Ruby on Rails. When I run "heroku create" I do not get "Git remote heroku added". Also, when I try to "git push heroku master" I get "fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly". On the sites like Stackflow there are similar situations but with additional error messages. Mine is only "fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly".  I also already edited the gem file. I notice that instead of loading the "first_app" that I'm trying to install, it installs the http: //murmuring-ravine-4822.herokuapp.com | git@heroku.com:murmuring-ravine-4822.git.
Please help,
Alex

Comment: Sort of sounds like an auth problem I ran into a while back.  Did you log in and do you know if you have a public key set up?

Comment: Have you gone onto Github and seen your source code in your repository is the same as on your computer? Have you signed onto Heroku and seen your application after clicking 'My Apps'?

Comment: Install the command line client via the toolbelt and if you installed it via a gem uninstall it. Can you create new applications via the web interface? This might be an issue with your public key.

Comment: Heroku is a commercial service, contact the customer support.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create your SSH key and upload to Heroku.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys

Comment: Thanks Thomas but it was something way simpler and dummer that that...I had not finalized github account set up.  Once I verified the account it worked!  UGH....

Answer (score 0):

Add application to Heroku git remote repository using below command.

```
heroku git:remote -a your-app-name
```

Then push application to Heroku master repository.

Useful link: [Creating a Heroku remote](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#creating-a-heroku-remote).

Answer (score -1):

Taken from [Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-solve-the-problem-Heroku-does-not-appear-to-be-a-git-repository) (worked for me August 2018):

Vinayak Sinha says:
"Your heroku app has a git repository, you can find that in app settings.

In your local git, add remote of that git repository, then you can fetch and push:

```
git remote add heroku (<=this is the remote name) remote_url"
```